# image src get lost when submitted in ckeditor5

Tags: javascript, php, file, file-upload, ckeditor

I used simple custom MyUploadAdapter following the ckeditor5 online document.

Images show up from both copy-paste and file upload dialog, and uploaded to the server. But once clicked save the textarea content to my server, the image src is empty, shown as:

```
<figure class="image"><img></figure>

<figure class="image"><img src="" alt="16 Days of Activism | The Rose Campaign - Women in Crisis"></figure>
```

The libray I am using:
https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/19.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js

Here are the codes:

```
function synchValues()
{
/*
    for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances)
        CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(){
   $.each( CKEDITOR.instances, function(instance) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("change", function(e) {
        for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    });
   });
});


    document.getElementById('editor').value = editor.getData();
*/



$('textarea.editor').each(function () {
   var $textarea = $(this);
   $textarea.val(CKEDITOR.instances[$textarea.attr('name')].getData());
});


    return true;
}



function MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin( editor ) {

    editor.plugins.get( 'FileRepository' ).createUploadAdapter = ( loader ) => {
        // Configure the URL to the upload script in your back-end here!
        return new MyUploadAdapter( loader );
    };
}

let editor;

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        extraPlugins: [ MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin ],


        styles: [
            // This option is equal to a situation where no style is applied.
            'full',

            'side',

            // This represents an image aligned to the left.
            'alignLeft',

            'alignCenter',

            // This represents an image aligned to the right.
            'alignRight'
        ],

        image: {
            upload:  {
                types: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'webp', 'tiff', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'm4v', 'm4a', 'm1v', 'm2v', 'mp2', 'mpa', 'mpe', 'mpeg', 'mpg', 'mpv2', 'wav', 'pdf']
                // Image upload feature options.
            }
        }
    } )
    .then( newEditor => {
        console.log( 'Editor was initialized', newEditor );
        editor = newEditor;
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.log( error );
    } );

Here is the upload class:

class MyUploadAdapter {
    constructor( loader ) {
        // The file loader instance to use during the upload.
        this.loader = loader;
    }


    // Initializes the XMLHttpRequest object using the URL passed to the constructor.
    _initRequest() {
        const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Note that your request may look different. It is up to you and your editor
        // integration to choose the right communication channel. This example uses
        // a POST request with JSON as a data structure but your configuration
        // could be different.
        xhr.open( 'POST', 'http://...../uploadc.php', true );
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
    }



    // Initializes XMLHttpRequest listeners.
    _initListeners( resolve, reject, file ) {
        const xhr = this.xhr;
        const loader = this.loader;
        const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${ file.name }.`;

        xhr.addEventListener( 'error', () => reject( genericErrorText ) );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'abort', () => reject() );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'load', () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    const response = xhr.response;
                    if ( response && (response.url || response.urls) ) {
                        resolve( response.url ? { default: response.url } : response.urls );
                    } else if ( response && response.error ) {
                        return reject( response.error.message );
                    } else {
                        resolve( response.url ? { default: response.url } : response.urls );
                    }

                } else {
                    return reject( genericErrorText );
                }
            }


        } );

        // Upload progress when it is supported. The file loader has the #uploadTotal and #uploaded
        // properties which are used e.g. to display the upload progress bar in the editor
        // user interface.
        if ( xhr.upload ) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', evt => {
                if ( evt.lengthComputable ) {
                    loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                    loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                }
            } );
        }
    }



    // Prepares the data and sends the request.
    _sendRequest( file ) {
        // Prepare the form data.
        const data = new FormData();

        data.append( 'upload', file );

        // Important note: This is the right place to implement security mechanisms
        // like authentication and CSRF protection. For instance, you can use
        // XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader() to set the request headers containing
        // the CSRF token generated earlier by your application.

        // Send the request.
        this.xhr.send( data );
    }



    // Starts the upload process.
    upload() {
        return this.loader.file
            .then( file => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
                this._initRequest();
                this._initListeners( resolve, reject, file );
                this._sendRequest( file );
            } ) );
    }

    // Aborts the upload process.
    abort() {
        if ( this.xhr ) {
            this.xhr.abort();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, nothing wrong with the code. This issue is caused by server side data not being clean:

it only allows registered users to do this file upload, which causes some unvisible stuff in the response, so xmlhttprequest cannot handle it properly.

I used ob_end_clean() to cast off cached data, and it works now

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I think you should try.**

```
ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#Content' ), {
        
    } )
        .then( editor => {
            window.editor = editor;

            editor.editing.view.document.on( 'keyup', ( evt, data ) => {
            //console.log( `You typed : ${ editor.getData()}` );               
            } );


            editor.plugins.get( 'FileRepository' ).createUploadAdapter = ( loader ) => {
                // Configure the URL to the upload script in your back-end here!
                return new MyUploadAdapter( loader );
        };

        
        editor.editing.view.document.on( 'change:isFocused', ( evt, data, isFocused ) => {
            //console.log( `View document is focused: ${ data }.` );
        } );

        //console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
        } )
                .catch( error => {
                    console.error( error.stack );
        } );
```

Your **MyUploadAdapter**

```
   class MyUploadAdapter {
    constructor( loader ) {
        // The file loader instance to use during the upload.
        this.loader = loader;
    }


    // Initializes the XMLHttpRequest object using the URL passed to the constructor.
    _initRequest() {
        const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Note that your request may look different. It is up to you and your editor
        // integration to choose the right communication channel. This example uses
        // a POST request with JSON as a data structure but your configuration
        // could be different.
        xhr.open( 'POST', 'http://...../uploadc.php', true );
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
    }

    // Initializes XMLHttpRequest listeners.
    _initListeners( resolve, reject, file ) {
        const xhr = this.xhr;
        const loader = this.loader;
        const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${ file.name }.`;

        xhr.addEventListener( 'error', () => reject( genericErrorText ) );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'abort', () => reject() );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'load', () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    const response = xhr.response;
                    if ( response && (response.url || response.urls) ) {
                        resolve( response.url ? { default: response.url } : response.urls );
                    } else if ( response && response.error ) {
                        return reject( response.error.message );
                    } else {
                        resolve( response.url ? { default: response.url } : response.urls );
                    }

                } else {
                    return reject( genericErrorText );
                }
            }


        } );

        // Upload progress when it is supported. The file loader has the #uploadTotal and #uploaded
        // properties which are used e.g. to display the upload progress bar in the editor
        // user interface.
        if ( xhr.upload ) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', evt => {
                if ( evt.lengthComputable ) {
                    loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                    loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                }
            } );
        }
    }



    // Prepares the data and sends the request.
    _sendRequest( file ) {
        // Prepare the form data.
        const data = new FormData();

        data.append( 'upload', file );

        // Important note: This is the right place to implement security mechanisms
        // like authentication and CSRF protection. For instance, you can use
        // XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader() to set the request headers containing
        // the CSRF token generated earlier by your application.

        // Send the request.
        this.xhr.send( data );
    }



    // Starts the upload process.
    upload() {
        return this.loader.file
            .then( file => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
                this._initRequest();
                this._initListeners( resolve, reject, file );
                this._sendRequest( file );
            } ) );
    }

    // Aborts the upload process.
    abort() {
        if ( this.xhr ) {
            this.xhr.abort();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and found a solution by sending a JSON response with the 'url' property.

In my case (I'm using Laravel), I implemented it like this:

```
return response()->json(['url' => $url]);
```

[This is where I found the solution.](https://dcblog.dev/upload-images-in-ckeditor-5-with-laravel#simple-image-adapter)

Answer (score -1):

Yes,
**Your are right.**
It only allows registered users to do this file upload.
If you upload image on server then you should write a function to upload image.
**Like this,**

We write this code in **C#** language.

```
[Authorize, HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImage()
{
    private string filepath = string.Empty;
    private string server = string.Empty;
    private HttpPostedFileBase file = null;
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        file = Request.Files[0];
        if (!Directory.Exists(string.Format(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImage"))))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(string.Format(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImage")));
        }

        server = string.Format(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImage/{0}"), file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(server);
    }

    filepath = string.Format("/UploadedImage/{0}", file.FileName);

    return Json(new { url = filepath});
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not seem to answer the question + check the formatting of your code. Why do you think you have the bottom half of the code green. It considers the code as string constant (see missing double quote on `Server.MapPath`)